# VBA searching through rows and their associated columns and hide column if there is nothing

Tags: vba, search, loops, hide

I am new to VBA programming. I would like to

- search through the worksheet, and find "N" or "TR" on row 6
- Then, For every cell in the column of "N" or "TR"
- if all the cells are blank, then delete/ hide the column
- if the cells are not blank, highlight the cells that are in blank

This sounds easy but I think it requires two for loops.

```
 Sub checkandhide()    
    Set r = Range("6:6")  
    Rows("7:7").Select  
    For Each Cell In r  
        Selection.Find(What:="N", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _  
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _  
            False, MatchByte:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate  
        'search for N  
        Application.Run "hidecolumn"  
    Next  
 End Sub  


Sub hidecolumn()
    Dim target As Range
    Dim dwn As Range

    Set dwn = Range(ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Address)
    ActiveCell.Select

    ActiveCell.Offset(6, 0).Select

    For Each Cell In dwn
        If Cell.Text = "" Then Columns.Delete
    Next      
End Sub
```

[attached example spreadsheet](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-mbWxnUGYXQ8/UdTP5k_XBtI/AAAAAAAAAA8/wSQW-PG043o/s872/help.png)

Comment: how many (approx.) columns are there in your sheet which you need to make this operation with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need two loops.
2. You mentioned you want to hide column but your code suggest you delete it (I kept solution which hides)
3. You didn't mentioned which is empty range (which cells are blank) to decide to hide the column- I assumed everything below 11th row.
4. Here is the code which is **tried and tested** with some comments inside it.

   ```
   Sub checkandhide()
   Dim r As Range
   Dim Cell As Range
   'don't run it for the complete row but from first to last cell in it
   Set r = Range("A6", Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))

   For Each Cell In r
       'you don't need find if you simply need to check value of the cell
       'let's assume we check for 'N' & 'TR'  but not 'n' or 'tr'
       If Cell.Value = "N" Or Cell.Value = "TR" Then

           'there are few possibilities to check if there is any value below _
           row 11 (?!) in analysed column. I would use this one:
           If Cells(Rows.Count, Cell.Column).End(xlUp).Row < 12 Then
               Cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
           End If

       End If
   Next
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot!!!! But I still have a problem. Is it able to highlight the cells that are filled when row 6 shows "N"/ "TR" (without hiding the column) and also highlight the cells that are empty if row 6 shows "Y"?

Comment: Could you also tell me what does it men by <12 in If Cells(Rows.Count, Cell.Column).End(xlUp).Row < 12?

Comment: answering second- this check if there is anything in column, this code goes to the last cell in column, move up like pressing Ctrl+UpArrow, and if it stops in row number lower than 12 then criteria are met.

Comment: for the first- ask separate question for that... but think of 'highlight empty cells'- in which area? all 1.000.000 rows in 'Y' column?? would be terrible inefficient...

Comment: Thanks a lot KazJaw!! Your answers are very helpful and I am a huge step towards my goal!