# Named Range Columns

Tags: excel, vba

How to range named area because I must do something wrong.

I want to loop each column in table(named area) and if all cells in that column are empty then hide him.
I know how to loop each cell in column etc. but there is my glitch when range is named area.
My inspiration is [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461130/vba-searching-through-rows-and-their-associated-columns-and-hide-column-if-there)

Comment: Post your current code.

Comment: Yes, post your code and clarify if you are working on a Table (*List Object*). Approach may vary if that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
dim c as long
with range("my_named_range")
    for c = 1 to .columns.count
        .columns(c).entirecolumn.hidden = not cbool(application.counta(.columns(c)))
    next c
end with
```

Comment: This is pretty smooth, can you help me with that application.counta(.columns(c)) because my cells are not blanks but     format is 0;-0;;@ so maybe if i use `If (Application.CountIf(.Columns(c), "0") = .Rows.Count) Then` but its syntax error, dont understand cbool and bolean function ..